# How to separate bloom-generate'd debian package into variants (release, -dev, -dbg)?

Tags: catkin, deb, ros-kinetic, rosdep, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to separate binary debian packages I can produce with `bloom-generate` and `debuild` into variants:

- release (only libraries and executables)
- -dev (headers, symlinks)
- -dbg (debugging symbols)

To give a more specific example - this is a toy workspace with 3 interdependent packages:

https://github.com/aurzenligl/study/tree/master/ros-distro

When using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and ros-kinetic, I can produce debian binary packages with `package_workspace.bash` script (installing rosdep rules by `install_rosdep_rules.bash` first), but I don't know how to separate -dev and -dbg parts from these packages. I have:

- `ros-kinetic-arx_0.1.2-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-bar_1.2.4-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-foo_3.4.5-0xenial_amd64.deb`

I aim for:

- `ros-kinetic-arx-dbg_0.1.2-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-arx-dev_0.1.2-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-arx_0.1.2-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-bar-dbg_1.2.4-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-bar-dev_1.2.4-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-bar_1.2.4-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-foo-dbg_3.4.5-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-foo-dev_3.4.5-0xenial_amd64.deb`
- `ros-kinetic-foo_3.4.5-0xenial_amd64.deb`

with correct dependencies among each other, so that all kinds of users:

- interested only in running,
- only in compiling/linking and
- only in debugging

would be satisfied. How can I achieve that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299788/how-to-separate-bloom-generate%27d-debian-package-into-variants-(release,--dev,--dbg)?/) by [aurzenligl](https://answers.ros.org/users/36857/aurzenligl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-06**:
Afaik this is not supported by Bloom at the moment. But as `.deb`s are just archives, extracting and manual patching is probably possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The debian toolchain has recently been updated to automatically create the debug packages.

We've been working on making sure that the buildfarm supports them: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/pull/545  https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment/issues/186 https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/32

However splitting out the development files requires manually creating the control file to split the headers from the runtime dependencies is not something that is easily automated. For hand curated debian packages manually applying a heuristic is relavely easy but there are a lot of corner cases to consider before automating it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aurzenligl](https://answers.ros.org/users/36857/aurzenligl/) on 2018-08-09**:
Would I be able to reuse the automatic debian `*-dbg` package generation using just `bloom-generate` if I don't intend to use entire `buildfarm` solution? If so - is ubuntu xenial (ros-kinetic) new enough to be able to use this feature?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-08-10**:
Yes, bloom is designed to generate standard gbp release repos that you can manually checkout and build debians from using gbp-buildpackage or dpkg-buildpackage on the right branch. If you dig into the buildfarm code you can find the exact invocation we use.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-10-04**:\

> If so - is ubuntu xenial (ros-kinetic) new enough to be able to use this feature?

The dbgsym packages were first automatically produced for Debian Stretch and Ubuntu Artful/Bionic.